# Setting Public statistics via insert on Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, statistics, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am uploading  a video to YouTube using the Java API like this:

```
    YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youTube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", video, videoInputStreamContent);

videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new UploadProcessListener());

uploadedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
```

Now the client wants to me to pre-set the option "Make video statistics on the watch page publicly available", but I could not find this option on the documentation of the insert.
Does anybody knows how to set this value?

[Setting I want to change on the Yoututbe Page after it was updated by the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJigh.png)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `status.publicStatsViewable`, which is included among the [videos.insert parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters).  The parameter is described in more detail on the [Overview page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties):

> This value indicates whether the extended video statistics on
>   the video's watch page are publicly viewable. By default, those
>   statistics are viewable, and statistics like a video's viewcount and
>   ratings will still be publicly visible even if this property's value
>   is set to false.

In your Java code, I believe you'll want to create a [`VideoStatus`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/VideoStatus.html) object and call `setPublicStatsViewable()`, and then set the status on your `video` object:

```
VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
status.setPublicStatsViewable(true);
video.setStatus(status);

// (your existing code)
YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = 
    youTube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", video, videoInputStreamContent);
...
```

Comment: thanks my friend. I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.